# Unable to stub @Shared fields

Tags: groovy, spock

I'm new to spock, and trying to experiment with some simple Mocks and Stubs. While playing around a little, I noticed that I'm unable to stub or mock @Shared fields. I couldn't find any such mention in the documentation. Is there's something I'm missing out in in the way setupSpec() or setup() works ?

```
package com.rsa.netwitness.cloud

import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

class MySpecification extends Specification {

    @Shared MyPojo pojo

    MyPojo pojo2

    def setup(){
        pojo2 = Mock(MyPojo)
    }
    def setupSpec(){
        pojo = Mock(MyPojo)
    }

    def "example 1"(){
        given:
        pojo.getValue() >> "foobar"

        expect: "fails"
        pojo.getValue() == "foobar"
    }

    def "example 2"(){
        given:
        pojo2.getValue() >> "foobarbaz"

        expect: "works"
        pojo2.getValue() == "foobarbaz"
    }

}

class MyPojo {

    public String value ;

    public String getValue(){
        return value ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported by Spock, please read [this](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/791) for further information.

There is no benefit from defining mocks/stubs as `@Shared`. Furthermore, you should avoid `@Shared` if you can since in breaks test isolation. Only use it for things that are costly to create and try to avoid mutating those.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
class MySpecification extends Specification {

    @Shared MyPojo pojo = Mock(MyPojo)

    def setupSpec(){
        pojo.getValue() >> "foobar"
    }

    def "example 1"(){
        expect: 
        pojo.getValue() == "foobar"
    }
}

class MyPojo {


    public String value ;

    public String getValue(){
        return value ;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

This would also work:

```
class MySpecification extends Specification {

    @Shared MyPojo pojo = Mock(MyPojo) {
        getValue() >> 'foobar'
    }

    def "example 1"(){
        expect: 
        pojo.getValue() == "foobar"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm more interested in why it doesn't work. does it have to do with the way spock works ?

Comment: "I'm more interested in why it doesn't work." - My mistake.  I just re-read your question and I see that you didn't ask how to do it.  Please disregard and I apologize for the noise.